# Rspec Running Tests Results in Validation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

For example:

I run a test and all asserts pass, but I run the test again, and in my case, I receive the following error:

Validation failed: Email has already been taken

It seems adding: sequence(:email) {|n| "nobody#{n}@xyz.com" } for factorygirl is pointless

The tests seem to pass sometimes and others fail for errors reasons like these.

Please advise on the problem/solution.

Comment: Are you clearing the test database before/after each run? If you run the tests, then manually run `rake db:test:prepare`, then run the tests again, do they pass or fail? (normally this is handled automatically by `database_cleaner` or transactional fixtures, but something could be configured incorrectly or your database could be in a bad state)

Answer (score 0):

try deleting all the records from tables before running test case.

eg:-

```
describe User do
  before(:each) do
    User.delete_all
  end

  it "validate e-mail" do
   (do staff..)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure it is a definitive solution, but i added random numbers to my product references on the factories with factorygirl using the lazy attributes.

Example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
     reference              {"AB"+rand(999).to_s}
     description            "Test Product"
     quantity               {(1..9999).to_a.sample}
     price_per_unit         {((1..999999).to_a.sample)/100.to_f}
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any "before(:all)" block? maybe you are missing the corresponding "after(:all)" to clean the data. before(:each) acts as a transaction so the database gets cleaned, before(:all) works like a normal query, yout have to handle the cleanup in an after(:all) block.